# Reference request: When is the set of critical values of $f : \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^m$ a countable set?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, differential-topology

Given a continuously differentiable function $f : U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^m$ (where $U$ is an open set), we say that $x$ is a critical point of $f$ if $Df(x)$ is not full rank. Let $C_f$ represent the set of all critical points of $f$. From Sard's theorem, we know that when $f$ satisfies certain regularity conditions, then $ f(C_f) $ has measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. A generalisation of this result states that (again, under suitable regularity) if $ A_r = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \text{rank}Df(x) < r \} $, then the Hausdorff dimension of $ f(A_r) $ is at most $r$, but it can be arbitrarily close to $r$.

My question is, (*) what 'nice' functions are known to have the property that $ f(C_f) $ is actually always a countable set?

For example, I think that this (*) would hold when $f : U \mapsto \mathbb{R}^m $ is analytic and $C_f \neq U$.

Also, in the case when $m=1$ and $C_f$ is a connected set, although we might expect that $f$ will be constant on $C_f$, Whitney [constructed](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-1/issue-4/A-function-not-constant-on-a-connected-set-of-critical/10.1215/S0012-7094-35-00138-7.short) a real-valued $C^1$ function of $2$ variables such that $C_f$ is an arc and $f(C_f)$ is not a constant and in fact contains an open set of $\mathbb{R}$. The same paper mentions that when $f$ is 'smooth enough', then "*$f$ must be constant on any connected critical set, as shown by
M. Morse and A. Sard in an unpublished paper*". But in my view, this shows that it is quite difficult to come up with such functions and I would expect 'generic' functions (in some appropriate sense) to be constant on each connected set of critical points, even given lower regularity.

Any thoughts or references regarding this are welcome!

Comment: By analytic do you mean analytic in each variable? If yes you could consider $f(x)=(x_1^2,0,\dots,0)$

Comment: I mean jointly analytic (afaik, analytic in each variable does not imply jointly analytic)

Comment: I see your point. I guess I need to specify that $C_f $ is not equal to the entire domain of $f$, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Consider the polynomial function
   $$
   f(x,y)=(x,y^2). 
   $$
   Then the set of critical values of $f$ is uncountable, equal to
   $$
   \{(x,0): x\in {\mathbb R}\}. 
   $$
   Hence, your conjecture about real-analytic functions fails.
2. On the other hand, if $f: U\to {\mathbb R}$ is a real-analytic function defined on an open connected subset $U\subset {\mathbb R}^n$, then the set of critical values of $f$ is countable, see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279852/critical-values-of-analytic-functions-of-several-variables).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your previous comment made me think about these aspects and I realised that indeed my belief was wrong.

Comment: [I'm leaving the question still open for a while though, in case someone else might have something interesting to add]